# Verificar decimales

Tags: javascript

```js
function c(n) {
  var v;
  if (n % 1 !== 0) v = parseFloat(n); // Verifico si el numero es decimal y uso parseFloat
  else v = parseInt(n); // Verifico si el numero es entero y uso parseInt

  return v; // Retorno el numero
}

console.log(c("45.2")); // Llamo a la función
```

Suponiendo que `JavaScript` no transformase las `string` en números, ¿cómo podría verificar que `n%1`, si está primero sería una `string`?

Comment: No termino de entender que es lo que quieres hacer y cual es el problema, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y explicar mejor que es lo que quieres?

Comment: Lo que necesitas es saber si es float o int antes de hacer el parse?

Comment: Si @Kenny, suponiendo que Javascript no los convirtiera en numeros

Comment: Podrias agregar esa aclaración a tu pregunta? Es que esta un poco confusa. Pues yo pensaria en buscar un punto o una coma en el string. Esta limitado a cierto conjunto de datos lo que le enviaras a la función o podria ser cualquier cosa? Porque si no, quizas deberias usar una expresión regular.

Comment: Pues como javascript los convierte a numeros es fácil, pero si no los conviertese, como sabria si el numero es entero o decimal? , ademas con lo del punto 1.0 o 9.00000000 también seria entero

Comment: ¿Quieres entonces comprobar si lo ingresado a la función es un string o es un décimal?

Answer (score 2):

Así puedes validar si es un string

```js
function esString(myVar){
  return (typeof myVar == 'string' || myVar instanceof String);
}

console.log(esString(1));
console.log(esString("1"));
console.log(esString(new String(1)));
```

Y siempre es recomendable hacer el parseo de string a numeros

```js
function esString(myVar){
      return (typeof myVar == 'string' || myVar instanceof String);
    }
    
function suma(var1, var2){
  
  var numVar1 = var1;
  
  var numVar2 = var2;

  if(esString(var1)){
      if(var1.indexOf(".")>=0)
        numVar1 = parseFloat(var1);
      else
        numVar1 = pareseInt(var1, 10);
  }

  if(esString(var2)){
      if(var2.indexOf(".")>=0)
        numVar2 = parseFloat(var2);
      else
        numVar2 = pareseInt(var2, 10);
  }
  console.log( numVar1 + numVar2 );
}

suma("5.2", 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedo entender de tu pregunta es que javascript hace la conversion por si solo y quieres saber como se verificaria si un `string` es decimal si javascript no hiciera la conversion automaticamente. Bueno en este caso solo buscando si tiene un punto con `indexOf()`, ya que los decimales siempre seran acompañados de un punto:

```js
function c(n) {
  var v;
  if (n.indexOf(".") > -1){
     console.log("decimal")
   v = parseFloat(n); 
  }else {
  console.log("int")
    v = parseInt(n); 
  }

  return v; // Retorno el numero
}

console.log(c("454.42")); 
 console.log(c("42"));
```

O con expresiones regulares buscando un punto en medio de numeros:

```js
    function c(n) {
      var v;
      if (/\d+\.\d+/g.test(n)){
         console.log("decimal")
       v = parseFloat(n); 
      }else {
      console.log("int")
        v = parseInt(n); 
      }

      return v; // Retorno el numero
    }

    console.log(c("454.42")); 
 console.log(c("42"));
```